# Histogram in python choosing bin sizes with sqrt method

Tags: python, histogram

Trying to generate the histogram with the sqrt method for bin sizes. What am I doing wrong? My code is below gives me error. Thank you.

> TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

```
values = [1,5,2,8,5,11,24,30,50]
x = len(values)
binsizes = math.sqrt(x)
plt.hist(values, bins = binsizes)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Does it give any error in particular?  For any particular line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`math.sqrt(x)` returns a float. The bins arg is expecting an integer. You need to cast binsizes to int at some point:

```
values = [1,5,2,8,5,11,24,30,50]
x = len(values)
binsizes = math.sqrt(x)
plt.hist(values, bins = int(binsizes))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to make your **math.sqrt to int**, if its not made to int you would always receive an error

> n = np.zeros(bins, ntype) TypeError: 'float' object cannot be
>   interpreted as an integer
>   **In your code binsizes is float type and hence need to be converted to int**

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
values = [1,5,2,8,5,11,24,30,50]
x = len(values)
print(x)
binsizes = int(math.sqrt(x))
plt.hist(values, bins = binsizes)
plt.show()
```